# How can I call one JavaScript file for many HTML file?

Tags: javascript, html

I am trying to do website which has more than one page.
In the `getYarismaciName` function I am tryin to get cards (in the first HTML page) innerHTML and sending `getJSON` function. In this function I am trying to add some HTML code in `.yarismaci-section` (in the second page) using innerHTML but in this part I get "Uncaught TypeError: Cannot set property 'innerHTML' of null"  error I guess js still searching `yarismaci-section` in the first HTML page but it is in the second page. How can I fix this error?

```
const cards = document.querySelectorAll(".card");

const getYarismaciName = function(){
cards.forEach((item) => {
    item.addEventListener("click",function(){
        let name=item.childNodes[3].innerHTML;
                
        getJSON(name);

    })
});
}
getYarismaciName();


const getJSON = function(name){
    const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("GET","data.json",true);

    xhr.onload=function(){
        if(this.status===200){
            let yarismacilar = JSON.parse(this.responseText);
            let html="";
            yarismacilar.forEach(person => { 
                if(person.name===name){
                    html=`
                            <div class="yarismaci-img" id="yarismaci__img">
                            <img src="${person.image}" alt="${person.name}">
                            </div>
                            <div class="yarismaci-des">
                            <h3 id="yarismaci__kimdir">${person.name} Kimdir ?</h3>
                            <p id="yarismaci__budur">${person.info}</p>
                                </div>  
                        
                        `;
                }
            });
            document.querySelector(".yarismaci-section").innerHTML=html;
        }
    }
    
    xhr.send();
}
```

Comment: I'm not sure what you are trying to do here. Are you trying to set the content of an element after an XHR request? Please clarify.

Comment: ı am getting name in the "getYarismaciName " function and sending it to getJSON function. I also  have json file. while ı am wander in json file with foreach if the names are same (getting from function and in json file) ı add it in html.

Answer (score 0):

You can check whether or not the element was found before trying to assign to it's `innerHTML` with an if statement.

Assign whatever is returned by the `querySelector` function to a variable then test to make sure that the variable isn't null or undefined before trying to use it.

```js
let element = document.querySelector(".yarismaci-section");
if(typeof(element) != 'undefined' && element != null)
    element.innerHTML = "Found .yarismaci-section";
else
    document.querySelector(".different-div").innerHTML = "Could not find .yarismaci-section";
```

```html
<div class="different-div"></div>
```

Comment: Thank you I checked it now and I got  "Could not find .yarismaci-section". But I still couldn't find how I can add HTML code using`innerHTML` in `.yarismaci-section`.  and why Js doesn not see my `.yarismaci-section`.

Comment: Is the javascript code on the first page and the .yarimaci-section on the second page? I don't see where you're changing to the second page, so .yarimaci-section will never exist. Using an `XMLHttpRequest` lets you interact with the server in some way without having to refresh the page.

Comment: Yes actually I added this Javascript file in both HTML file. I  got name from first page and if it is same the name in json I tried to show it in the second page. `.card` div is in the first page `.yarismaci-section` div is in the second page. Mainly idea was when ı click the card in the first page , the second page shows up and show the name ı checked in if condition.